# Obligation avec « à »

Tags: grammaire

Dans les phrases comme « le livre à lire » ou « la chose à donner », quel est le rôle du mot *à*?
Je le comprends comme « qu'on doit » mais je me demande comment un tel usage a pu apparaître.

Answer (score 2):

Le site de l'Académie française cite les très nombreuses utilisations de la préposition "à".

Parmi celles-ci :

**VII** À suivi d’un infinitif peut indiquer une destination nécessaire, une obligation permanente ou temporaire. *Un livre à lire et à relire. Un spectacle à voir. La marche à suivre. Prix à débattre. Une personne à récompenser. L’homme à abattre. Votre travail est à refaire. Avoir trois enfants à nourrir. Avoir quelque chose à faire et, elliptiquement, avoir à faire. Il n’en est que plus à estimer. Ce n’est pas à dédaigner. C’est à prendre ou à laisser.*

A l'origine, selon cette référence, "à" (latin *ad*) indiquait une destination, ce qui est à rapprocher d'un objectif à atteindre.

En simplifiant un peu :

Destination à atteindre -> objectif à atteindre -> obligation

Comment: Lien: https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A0004